# Regex only searching part of a string

Tags: regex, string

I'm trying to do some validation on a string.

```
Y0 40 98 86 A
```

I would like to be able to replace the `0`'s which occur in the first 2 characters ie `Y0` with O's.

I know how to do the replace part but am struggling **to just select that** first 0.

It should match all 0's within that first two characters. Ie `00` `0Z` etc

To clarify, I don't mind what language I just need helping making the Regex Selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## One-step replacement

Thanks to @Rawing for the comment:

```
"00 40 98 86 A".gsub(/^0|(?<=^.)0/, 'O')
# "OO 40 98 86 A"
```

The regex means :

- start of the string, followed by:

  - zero, or
  - a character, followed by a zero.

Another variant by @SebastianProske:

```
"A0 40 98 86 A".gsub(/(?<!..)0/, 'O')
# "AO 40 98 86 A"
```

It means : `a 0, but only when not preceded by two characters`.

Here's a [test](https://regex101.com/r/m15ma9/1).

## Two steps replacement

It might be easier to do it in two steps. Replace the first character by `O` if it's a `0`, then replace the second character if it's a `0`.

Here's a ruby example with a matching group:

```
"Y0 40 98 86 A".sub(/^0/,'O').sub(/^(.)0/,'\1O')
# "YO 40 98 86 A"
```

You could also use a lookbehind:

```
"Y0 40 98 86 A".sub(/^0/,'O').sub(/(?<=^.)0/,'O')
=> "YO 40 98 86 A"
```

Comment: Yes I' m afraid It may come to that although it would be preferable to select them all in one.

Comment: Why not merge those two regexes into a single one? `/^0|(?<=^.)0/`

Comment: So there's no way to think about it like: `^.{2}` to select the first 2 characters and then matching inside the first match wit ha simple `0`?

Comment: @SebastianProske: Thanks, that's even cleaner.

Comment: The regex you provided in your example is perfect thank you.

Comment: Well you could also use just basic string comparison, this doesn't sound like a regex problem at all.

Comment: If only. I have to use regex through this application *Sigh*